# How to make Mongodb autorun in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am on Win7. I run MongoDB with command: >mongod --dbpath=C:/mongo/
What worries me that the service require the cmd window to be always open. 
I wonder is there a way to make Node.js(Express) run this command automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for development, I don't see the problem running MongoDB in a CMD. If it bothers you that much, you could just run it as a Service as described on the official page [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#manually-create-a-windows-service-for-mongodb). On a production System, you should do this anyways.

You could also try using `child_process` to startup the Database - but thats not a good Idea as it tangles your app with your database, which is pretty ugly (and will make it hard for other developers on your project)

Comment: Thanks for the info, it was really right on spot! I will leave MongoDB it as it is now, as I don't have much trust in Win OS(I can't install Ubuntu because of dynamic HDD setup).